# How to connect apache Guacamole in a ubuntu instance of google cloud?

Tags: ubuntu, rdp, guacamole

Hi guys I would like to know how to connect guacamole with a instance of ubuntu created in google cloud?

I followed this [tutorial](https://jasoncoltrin.com/2017/10/04/setup-guacamole-remote-desktop-gateway-on-ubuntu-with-one-script/)  butI have problems with the connection, Guacamole is installed in the same machine of google cloud, I have the static ip address and installed the ubuntu GUI and firewall rules, but I don't  have access to password of the OS I don't understand how get it.

Sorry for my english.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the Windows machine or to the Ubuntu machine? The selected protocol is RDP, this is typical for Windows machines.

In principle, you should supply un/pw for the target machine, not for the host running Guacamole.

Comment: That is true, I tried with  NVC and works fine, thanks man.